# Loop for exactly one second

Tags: java, android, timing

I am trying to create an Android app that records a runner's position every second. However, I'm finding it is takes slightly more than one second when it finishes.

Here is my code:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        if (getIfRunning() == true) {
            try {
                if (location2 != null) {
                    Float distanceFromLast = totalDistance(location2);
                    addToDistance(distanceFromLast);
                }
                getCoords();
                mMap.clear();
                markOldCoords();
                writeCoords();
                setCount();
                updateScreen();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        Long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 - time);
    }
};
handler.post(run);
```

Comment: [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29): *Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run **after** the specified amount of time elapses.* So yeah, it will not run *exactly* at the specified time, just at some time after it.

Comment: One thing you can do ... create your own `HandlerThread` and base your `Handler` off of that. Why? If you use the default constructor for `Handler`, it's most likely (depending on where you construct it) using the UI thread. Well, a lot of other things use that thread as well, so your `Runnable` will have to content with other usages of that thread.

Comment: Great ill give it a try! Thanks for all your help

Comment: Why not use the LocationListener and subscribe for it's updates ? GPS will track your runner, it will not be a timed thing, but will be accurate, for better results you can use [Google Location API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener)

Comment: Consider using `CountdownTimer`. This will make it unnecessary to keep track of start time.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, you can't get exact timing like this. Timers will always wake up slightly early or late due to what else the system is doing at the time. The best you can do is to accept that it will never be perfect and update your code accordingly to find out the times that you were actually triggered.

Comment: any suggestions for a better method, it will be almost 15 seconds off after 5 minutes which is not accurate enough for most users.

Comment: @NathanMay Remember the *first* timestamp, then calculate wait time from that, in order to prevent cumulative skew, which is what you're experiencing right now.

Comment: @Andreas isn't that what i have already done? I find the time before the methods are called, after they are called and find the difference. Sorry, new at this

Comment: @NathanMay No. You find the time at the beginning of each execution (measurement), not at the beginning of the (jogging) run.